# Tiling divs top/bottom right/left, maximum # of divs horizontally?

Tags: html, css

I have four `div`s laid out in a sequential order. I want each to take a corner of the page provided the content will fit, otherwise arrange sequentially vertically.

```css
#pptopleft,
#pptopright,
#ppbottomleft,
#ppbottomright {
 text-align: center;
 border: 1px solid black;
 width: 50%;
}
#ppcontainer {
    border: 1px solid black;
    font-size: 120%;
    min-height: 250px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-left: 50px;
    margin-right: 50px;
    padding-left: 3px;
    padding-right: 3px;
    padding-top: 3px;
    padding-bottom: 3px;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="ppcontainer">
    <div id="pptopleft">#1</div>
    <div id="pptopright">#2</div>
    <div id="ppbottomleft">#3</div>
    <div id="ppbottomright">#4</div>
</div>
```

If they can fit, I'd like them to each take 50% width of the parent container, but if they need to be stacked vertically, each should take 100% width. Something like the below:

```
//contents of each div will fit without wrapping
1 2
3 4

//contents of each div will not fit without wrapping
1
2
3
4
```

The latter maybe for smaller resolutions or mobile devices.

What can I do to achieve this using CSS?

Comment: Add `float: left;` and `box-sizing: border-box;` to divs.

Comment: @gator, sorry, you deleted your other question before I managed to post this: http://jsfiddle.net/cuv3zwxs/1/ (might be helpful - I always forget about flex!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Media queries could help with this. For example, add the following after your current CSS:

```
@media all and (max-width: 500px) {
    #pptopleft,
    #pptopright,
    #ppbottomleft,
    #ppbottomright {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

Change the `500px` to match whatever breakpoint you want, and set your existing divs to `float: left`.

Answer (score 0):

Use Bootstrap: and structure your div as following

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div id="1" class="col-md-6"></div>
    <div id="2" class="col-md-6"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div id="3" class="col-md-6"></div>
    <div id="4" class="col-md-6"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```